# Android ArrayList item in ListView

Tags: android, motodev-studio

So I have this list which uses values from an ArrayList (and I can't use String[] because the user must add items to the list, and I can't do .add to the String[]). But now I have problems with onItemClick method. I want to get the text from item selected, and my book says the following should work:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    dodaj.setText(values[arg2]);

}
```

But I get the following error: **The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList**
What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is "values" an ArrayList? if so use

```
dodaj.setText( (String)values.get( arg2 ) );
```

Comment: (Upvote for lain_b) You cannot use the `[]` to access data in a ArrayList, this only works for basic arrays like `String[]`. Also if `values` is declared as `ArrayList<String>` you can simply use: `dodaj.setText(values.get(arg2));`.

Comment: Yes this works. Now could you explain what is that index (arg2), what does it mean and what is it for?

Comment: arg2 is the position of the item in the listview. I usually rename it position ( or pos ).

Comment: and if you could also explain the other values (arg1, arg3) that would be great

Comment: arg1 is the view representing the list item clicked and arg3 I had to look up http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

you will have to convert arraylist to array using `arraylist.toarray()`

Answer (score 0):

With ArrayList you always use

```
arrayList.get(index);
```

Recommended way is to add a toString() method to your items/Objects so that it returns the preferred field.

```
public Student()
{
    ...
    ...
    public String toString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Now you can use arrayList.get(int index). It will print our the output of toString().